# "How expected" vs "how predictable"

Tags: difference

There is usage of "how unexpected" as a phrase, but when you mean the opposite, why does "how predictable" sound more natural, compared to "how expected"? Is it a collocation?

I believe the sense of "to what degree or extent" should be the correct one here, but there seems not to be a restriction of which adjectives to use.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this… but it made me think. Perhaps it's a percentage game vs black/white certainty. "I expected you here at 2" [100% because that is what was agreed] "but you predictably didn't turn up until 3" [with 60% predictability based on previous history]. "You unexpectedly turned up at my door" [I was 100% not expecting you, you said you were away this weekend]. "You got drunk & fell over… again" [high predictability based on previous habit]

Comment: Could I ask what you mean by "there seems not to be a restriction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said it yourself, this is a matter of usage. You don't argue with usage. Faced with usage, ours not to reason why...

As an example, you commonly say "make a mistake", as in:

> *Don't worry, we all make mistakes.* (Oxford Dictionary)

Now imagine you want to correct something people have said, and even though you are quite confident about it, you are trying to be polite. Will you say:

*If I haven't made a mistake, the emperor has no clothes.*

Well you could. In the same way that you could say "how expected", but that's now how some English guy decided to put it hundreds of years ago. He/She went for this:

*If I'm not mistaken, the emperor has no clothes.*

And that's the usage now. It's the "more correct" form. It sounds and feels better.

Having said that, there's usually a loose logic running through the fabric of the language that we may sometimes manage to catch hold of.

In our specific case, I think the key lies in the "tone":

**"How unexpected" is a simple expression of surprise.**
**"How predictable" is sarcastic.**

That's why "predictable" fits in much better:

> **expected**: that you think will happen (Oxford Dictionary)
> *Double the expected number of people came to the meeting.*

> **predictable**: (often disapproving) behaving or happening in a way that you would expect and therefore boring (Oxford Dictionary)
> **The ending of the book was entirely predictable.**